# Localize Wix Bundle Bootstrapper

Tags: localization, wix, burn

I localized file `hyperlinkthemt.wxl` (pl-pl). But my bootstrapper just shows up and then disappears in a second and nothing more happens. I was trying to solve the problem and noticed that I can't use polish letters in `hyperlinktheme.wxl`.
Is there any way to change that. I was trying to do something with `HyperLinkTheme.wxl`:

```
<WixLocalization Culture="pl-pl" Language="1045" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
```

but it didnt help. As you may know for bundle projects one can't change localization.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a log file in your %TEMP% folder that should show a little more detail what is wrong. Chances are the .wxl file is not saved in UTF8 and cannot be loaded.